# adding ne column into db by iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have an df that looks like this;

```
 Date            
09-11-2020
02-11-2020
..
09-11-2019
02-11-2019
```

where I want to add a new column through values of another df called "repo".

which looks like this:

```
Date         Lending
25-10-2019     14
13-12-2019.    12
17-01-2020     11
20-10-2020.    10
```

repo dataframe contains dates of changes.

I want to add those lending values into my df as a new column by properiet date.

my expected output is this:

```
df

output:

Date.       Lending
09-11-2020   14 
02-11-2020.  14
..
09-11-2019.  10
02-11-2019.  10
```

my initial trial was to write an fuction as: (date's of repo and df doesn't have to match)

```
def RfAdder(start,end,repo):     
    start = dt.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end = dt.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')
    
    df.loc[(data.Date > start) & (data.Date < end), 'Rf' ] = repo
```

then call it in loop of each rows of repo

```
for index, row in repo.iterrows():
    RfAdder('%s'%row.Date,'%s'%row.shift(1).Date,row.Lending)
```

but im getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-8d547a9f86e6> in <module>
      4 
      5 for index, row in repo.iterrows():
----> 6     RfAdder('%s'%row.Date,'%s'%row.shift(1).Date,row.Lending)

<ipython-input-93-cc3dc208275f> in RfAdder(start, end, repo)
      3         end = start
      4 
----> 5     start = dt.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
      6     end = dt.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')
      7 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    576     format string."""
--> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
--> 362                           data_string[found.end():])
    363 
    364     iso_year = year = None

ValueError: unconverted data remains:  00:00:00
```

I think this error is caused because when I do row.shift(1), at the last row there no other row above.. so its missing value

and I wonder what would be the best and easiest way to do this operation ?

thx in advance